# Is it possible to build an air compressor with no moving parts?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is it physically possible to build an air compressor with no moving parts? A thermodynamic cycle capable of compressing air with no moving parts and operate it in stationary way.

**EDIT**

I will add a constraint. It must be compressed using a heat source of any kind.

Comment: To compress air, you need to change the volume. How would you envisage to do that without moving parts?

Comment: Of course it is possible, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_pump_(physics)

Comment: Isn't it called a pressure cooker?

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear, but I mentioned a thermodynamic cycle and what I mean is if it is possible to compress air with no moving parts using a heat source.

Comment: Cross posted to engineering.SE: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/2832/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been crossposted on engineering.SE ( http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2832/is-it-possible-to-build-an-air-compressor-with-no-moving-parts )

Comment: @Floris magnets

Comment: Or lasers. Both would probably work in a ridiculously expensive way

Comment: I am still stuck on the idea of "operating in a stationary way". Meaning that it has to be some kind of tube with air coming in one side, going out the other with a higher pressure. Are photons a "moving part"?

Comment: @Floris No, photons can't not move, so I don't think they count as moving parts.

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is, using electrostatic forces. See the details here: [Electrostatic Fluid Accelerator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_fluid_accelerator) I should add that it can't lead to a high compression ratio like a mechanical compressor, but technically it does compress the gas in the vicinity of the charging source. And that leads to flow.

A perhaps more interesting followup question: can you conceive some electrostatic means, perhaps by progressive staging that leads to higher compression?

Comment: To obtain, convert and transport electricity you need moving parts. Although the answer is correct, I meant if it can be done from a heat source.

Comment: @user3368561: you don't need any moving parts to obtain, convert and transport electricity.

Comment: ¿No? So, how is it done? Turbines, generators, contact breakers, cooling systems, etc.

Comment: @user3368561 What about solar panels, peltier elements or piezoelectricity?

Comment: @fibonatic: Scratch piezoelectricity. It requires very little movement (as much as the compressed crystal yields), but still. OTOH, add nuclear thermoelectric - RTG batteries, electrochemical (standard batteries), pyroelectric, electromagnetic with magnetic field affected by Curie temperature, or capturing electromagnetic waves (big antenna, "detector radio"), and possibly a few more. And all of the driving circuitry can be solid-state, there are even oscillators that don't use vibrating quartz.